# How do you change the origin to your current cells location in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, cells, vba

Is there a simple way to change the origin to say, your Active Cell? Similar to Java Cartesian coordinate system? Is there any way to do that? So if my active cell is at (5,4) can I change that to become the new (1,1)?

Comment: You could delete the rows and columns before your values... But that's like a hack...

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(1,1)` without anything before it defaults to "Activebook.cells(1,1)`. Instead you can refer to the range to qualify it:

```
 Range("D5:IV100000").Cells(1,1)
```

Which will mean cell `D5` or Activebook.Cells(5,4)

Comment: How do I set the range with the activecell as the new 1,1? I have a pointer variable that is equal to ActiveCell.Adress(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False). And then I want to set the new origin with something like Range("pointer:IV100000").Cells(1,1). How do I do that?

Comment: The point is that there is no "1,1". It's a relative path based on the range that precedes it like `Range("A5").Cells(1,1)` means cell "A5". The `Cells` property is the relative path from the range. If no range is provided then `cells(1,1)` refers to the `ActiveSheet`. So your question of "How do I set the range with the activecell as the new 1,1" is meaningless. There is no absolute "1,1". Specify the range you care about `Range("D5")` then specify the relative position of the cell you want `Range("D5").cells(1,5)` or `Range("D5").Offset(0,5)` or what-have-you.

Comment: Also, sorry for the wait on the reply. I was in a remote area for the last week with no internet

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Offset` property.

So, if your current `ActiveCell` was cell D5, then `ActiveCell.Offset(10, 7)` refers to the cell 10 rows below it and 7 columns to the right (i.e. cell K15).

Alternatively, you could just use the `Cells` property (as per JNevill's answer) where `ActiveCell.Cells(11, 8)` would refer to K15 if the `ActiveCell` was currently D5.

The major difference between the two methods is that `Offset` is effectively zero-based (i.e. `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)` is the same as `ActiveCell`) while `Cells` is effectively one-based (i.e. `ActiveCell.Cells(1, 1)` is the same as `ActiveCell`).